# TextField race condition? onValueChange is adding initial value multiple times while typing (randomly) - Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I have the following code in my activity:

```
        setContent {
            var testingText by remember { mutableStateOf("InitialValue") }
            TextField(
                value = testingText,
                onValueChange = { testingText = it },
                label = { Text("Testing") },
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            )
        }
```

While running on an emulator, typing anything at the end of the text field, around 1 out of ~5 times - the text that I type ends up getting "InitialValue" added to whatever I type. See the below screenshot:

[image: text field]

I believe this trivial example is following the official docs. Wondering what is causing this race condition, could it be a bug? Am I doing something wrong? Maybe emulator/IME issue?

On 1.0.1 of compose.

Comment: I agree your code does follow the tutorial. Do you see the same behavior if you move the block into its own @Composable method?

Comment: Yep, I actually was surprised to see the issue happen when I made a simple example like this. Noticed this in an app I was working on, figured it was something in my state observation/view model setup but even this has same problem.

Comment: I also cannot seem to repro the issue on a real device, seems specific to my emulators (API 27,28, pixel 2) and using laptop (mbp) keyboard.

Comment: Is your laptop an M1 by chance?

Comment: no it is a 2015 MBP, AS Arctic Fox 2020.3.1

Comment: Is this problem appears on newly created compose project? Check out of it’s the same on api 31. I suggest you [creating](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=612128&template=1253476) an issue on compose issue tracker, including info about emulator versions you’re facing troubles with

Comment: I started a new project with (emulator api 30, arm64 Pixel 4) and did not see this issue.

Comment: Yea I created a from scratch compose project using the wizard, empty compose activity. Same issue on emulator API 27. Will create an issue on issue tracker.

Comment: Also tested on emulator API 30 and the issue does not happen, seems specific to 27, 28...(maybe others too, only tested on 27, 28, 30)

Comment: @Eggman87 did you create that issue? Do you have a link?

Comment: @Dambakk sorry I did not, meant to get around to it but the issue only impacted emulators and was on a time crunch with the project I was working on.